# Ubuntu 16.04 clean installation doesnt detect wireless wifi

Tags: wireless, 16.04

```
carlos@carlos-Satellite-L515:~$ sudo lspci 
[sudo] password for carlos: 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07) 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07) 
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07) 
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03) 
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03) 
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03) 
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03) 
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03) 
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03) 
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03) 
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03) 
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03) 
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03) 
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03) 
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03) 
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93) 
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03) 
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03) 
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03) 
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02) 
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192E/RTL8192SE Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01) 

carlos@carlos-Satellite-L515:~$ sudo lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b120 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
carlos@carlos-Satellite-L515:~$ 

softmac_mgmt_xmit():insert to waitqueue, queue_index:6!

 [ 6998.224057] softmac_mgmt_xmit():insert to waitqueue, queue_index:6!

ATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03) 
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03) 
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 02) 
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192E/RTL8192SE Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` and also: `rfkill list all` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Hi thanks for yor answer, here the results:carlos@carlos-Satellite-L515:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192E/RTL8192SE Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8192] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192E/RTL8192SE Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8152]
 Kernel driver in use: rtl819xE
carlos@carlos-Satellite-L515:~$ rfkill list all   enter doesnt return nothing but WiFi is not working. have to switch to wired conection to send this post.

Comment: Let's also see: `lsmod | grep 819` Thanks.

Comment: carlos@carlos-Satellite-L515:~$ lsmod | grep 819
r8192e_pci            135168  0
rtllib                155648  1 r8192e_pci
rtl8192se              65536  0
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8192se
rtlwifi                77824  2 rtl_pci,rtl8192se
mac80211              737280  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8192se
snd                    81920  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
r8169                  81920  0
carlos@carlos-Satellite-L515:~$ 

Thanks for your help,carlos

Comment: You have two drivers loaded which probably conflict. I will suggest that you blacklist one and see if the wireless starts working.

Answer (score 2):

You have two drivers loaded which probably conflict.

It is a bit unusual, but this is one of very few examples of two different drivers that claim the same device and probably conflict. I will suggest that you blacklist one and see if the wireless starts working.

It is a bit of guesswork to see which one works, and perhaps works the best. Let's try one first:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8192se"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot and tell us if the wireless is working.

Comment: Hi: I did it, worked a few minutes and then again disconected. I quit, buyed a USB Tp-Link adapter and wifi fly. Thanks a lot for your help